# How to set normal button color?

Tags: android, xml

I have set a background for my linear layout. But my button is covered under this color. I need normal button color.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/expandable"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="Delete"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/content_discard" />

</LinearLayout>
```

My layout [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PkhlU.png)

Please my help me out.

Comment: try this under your button : android:background="@null"  this will make the button default background dissapear

Comment: @SayedJalilHassan its not solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
android:background="@android:drawable/btn_default"
```

Example :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/expandable"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@android:drawable/btn_default"
        android:text="Delete" />

</LinearLayout>
```

You will get following output :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In your button tag write this:

```
   <Button
   android:background = "#D3D3D3"/>
```